# How do I execute a shell-command in background?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Here's a simple defun to run a shell script:

```
(defun bk-konsoles ()
  "Calls: bk-konsoles.bash"
  (interactive)
  (shell-command (concat (expand-file-name "~/its/plts/goodies/bk-konsoles.bash ")
                         (if (buffer-file-name) 
                             (file-name-directory (buffer-file-name)))
                         " &") 
                  nil nil))
```

If I start a program with no ampersand - it start the script, but blocks emacs until I close the program, if I don't put ampersand it gives error:

```
/home/boris/its/plts/goodies/bk-konsoles.bash /home/boris/scl/geekgeek/: exited abnormally with code 1.
```

**Edit**:

So now I'm using:

```
(defun bk-konsoles ()
  "Calls: bk-konsoles.bash"
  (interactive)
  (shell-command (concat (expand-file-name "~/its/plts/goodies/bk-konsoles.bash ") 
                         (if (buffer-file-name) 
                             (file-name-directory (buffer-file-name))) 
                         " & disown") 
                 nil nil)
  (kill-buffer "*Shell Command Output*"))
```

**Edit 2**:

Nope - doesn't work:

```
(defun bk-konsoles ()
  "Calls: bk-konsoles.bash"
  (interactive)
  (let ((curDir default-directory))
    ;; (shell-command (concat "nohup " (expand-file-name "~/its/plts/goodies/bk-konsoles.bash ") curDir) nil nil)
    (shell-command (concat (expand-file-name "~/its/plts/goodies/bk-konsoles.bash ") 
                           curDir "& disown") nil nil)
    (kill-buffer "*Shell Command Output*")))
```

keeps emacs busy - either with `disown`, or `nohup`.

Here's a script I'm running if it might be of help: [bk-konsoles.bash](https://github.com/bk322/bk-goodies/blob/master/bk-konsoles.bash)

Comment: hint: use `async-shell-command' instead

Comment: @kindahero - `async-shell-command` just adds the ampersand behind the scenes if one isn't present. If that worked, then what he has posted would also work.

Comment: You can use `disown` like this: `your-command & diswon`.

Comment: @Daimrod: `your-command & diswon` solves it! Please make it an answer - so I can accept it.

Comment: I think the problem is konsole. `(shell-command "x-term &")` does what you expect, but `(shell-command "konsole &")` opens and closes konsole immediately. Something about the way konsole is started seems to be causing the problem.

Comment: seems like a good reason to study `urxvt`.

Comment: @Tyler: You comment made me try `2>&1 > /dev/null &` which is a success. If You'll make it an answer - I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is konsole.

```
(shell-command "xterm &")
```

does what you expect, opening an xterm in a new window and returning control to Emacs. However,

```
(shell-command "konsole &")
```

opens and closes konsole immediately. Something about the way konsole is started seems to be causing the problem. I think KDE apps have their own system for launching apps, but I'm not sure. In any case, I don't think the problem is on the Emacs side here.

Comment: Just as a side note, I came here because I simply wanted to run an interactive shell within an emacs buffer window, and perhaps others will simply want to do the same, and it's pretty straight forward on a GNU Emacs install on a Debian box: "M-x term" where M is the alt key. This will run a subshell with input and output through an Emacs buffer. You can then give commands interactively. Full terminal emulation is available.

Answer (score 2):

You can either use `nohup` or `disown` like this:

```
$ your_command & disown
$ nohup your_command
```

See [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/difference-between-nohup-disown-and) on stackexchange for a description of the difference.

Comment: Cool! Take a look at the [continuation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10772821/value-of-the-dired-directory) of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Oh I solved it:

```
(shell-command (concat (expand-file-name "~/its/plts/goodies/bk-konsoles.bash ")
                curDir " 2>&1 > /dev/null & disown") nil nil)
```

and I also call konsole with `2>&1 > /dev/null &` in my bash script. Works silently!