# How to get folder path in dired-mode?

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

I can get the file path with:

```
(message (file-name-directory (or buffer-file-name load-file-name)))
```

But if the buffer in dired-mode, the above code evaluates to nil.

How can I get the folder path in dired-mode with elisp?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's `dired-directory`, however [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10772821/value-of-the-dired-directory) indicates that it is unreliable in certain circumstances, and that `default-directory` is a better choice.

- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `default-directory` <kbd>RET</kbd>
- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `dired-directory` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: Thank you. It works. But the path is like "~/dired-path". I need "/home/user/dired-path". How to convert?

Comment: `(expand-file-name default-directory)`

Comment: Thanks. I just want to say "I get it". The (file-truename path) is also worked.